# Permission request in Flutter

Tags: flutter, permissions

How can I request permission for accessing the device microphone for recording audio in Flutter?
I have tried looking this up but haven't been able to find a clear answer.

Comment: There is a package called `permission_handler` for requesting permission: https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

Comment: @StewieGriffin Yes, I am aware of that package. But how do I need to use it is what I am not getting. I have added the line: 

await Permission.microphone.request();

But it does not work.

Comment: can you show us what you have acheived till now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
await _askingPermission();

Future<String> _askingPermission() async {
  final PermissionStatus permissionStatus =
    await _getPhonePermission();
  if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted){
    //permission is granted
  } else{
    //permission denied or undermined
  }
}

Future<PermissionStatus> _getPermission() async {
  final PermissionStatus permission = await Permission.microphone.status;
  if (permission != PermissionStatus.granted &&
      permission != PermissionStatus.denied) {
    final Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> permissionStatus =
        await [Permission.microphone].request();
    return permissionStatus[Permission.microphone] ??
        PermissionStatus.undetermined;
  } else {
    return permission;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this line in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Comment: where in the manifest file